# Optimize Woocommerce function that show specific products only in specific roles

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the following function that runs on catalogue page and shows or hides specific products from users based on their role. If the user is customer then he can see the products that have checked the set_catalog_visibility (ACF).

The issue is that this function is slowing down my catalogue and i need to optimize it so it will run faster.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function( $query ){

$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_woocommerce()) {
    if (!check_user_role(array('customer','administrator')) || !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $product_ids = get_post_ids_by_meta_key_and_value('prd_clients', 1);
        foreach($product_ids as $id){
            // Get an instance of the product
            $product = wc_get_product($id);
            // Change the product visibility
            $product->set_catalog_visibility('hidden');
            // Save and sync the product visibility
            $product->save();
        }
    }
    else{
        $product_ids = get_post_ids_by_meta_key_and_value('prd_clients', 1);
        foreach($product_ids as $id){
            // Get an instance of the product
            $product = wc_get_product($id);
            // Change the product visibility
            $product->set_catalog_visibility('visible');
            // Save and sync the product visibility
            $product->save();
        }
    }
    
}
```

});

Comment: "I need to optimize it so it will run faster" is incredibly general and will likely lead to opinionated answers. You should start by researching different ways to achieve the same result, *then* once you hit a wall with making that other option reality should you ask a question.

Comment: @meropis man its simple what i am writing! I ask if someone knows a better way to write this code because it takes 5 -6 sec to run on catalogue. Its not incredibly general

Answer (score 0):

You can done it simply like this:

```php
add_action(
    'pre_get_posts',
    function( $query ) {
        if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_woocommerce() ) {
            if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ( is_user_logged_in() && ! check_user_role( array( 'customer', 'administrator' ) ) ) ) {
                $product_ids = get_post_ids_by_meta_key_and_value( 'prd_clients', 1 );

                if ( ! empty( $product_ids ) ) {
                    $query->set( 'post__not_in', $product_ids );
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```